# Angular: hide elements

Tags: angular, observable

I'm getting json data from API. After that I'm making the table with this data.

```
getValues(): Observable<Value[]> {
    return this.http.get<Value[]>(this.valuesUrl);
}
```

**component.html**

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody *ngFor="let value of values">
            <tr *ngFor="let sku of value.skus">
                <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{sku.id}}"></td>
                <td>{{value.group.name}}</td>
                <td>{{sku.name}}</td>
                <td class="price">{{sku.price}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<button class="btn" (click)="addToCart()">Add to cart</button>
```

I've checkboxes for all entries in the table. I need to delete the checked entries from the fetched array after click on button. I think I should use filter to do that but I'd error of can't read property of filter.

Comment: Do you want to delete item in the array and reflect the change in the table?

Comment: @MaihanNijat, yes, I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an example to elaborate this.

Markup:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let value of values; let i = index;">
        <tr>
            <input type="checkbox" (change)="addChecked(i, $event.target.checked)"/>
            <td>Delete</td>
            <td>{{value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button (click)="delete()">Delete</button>
```

Logic:

```
export class App {
    values = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    checked = [];

    constructor() {
    }

    addChecked(i, isChecked) {
        isChecked ? this.checked.push(i) : this.checked.splice(i, 1);
    }

    delete() {
        for (var i = this.checked.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            this.values.splice(this.checked[i], 1);
        }
        this.checked = [];
    }
}
```

Let's assume the data fetched from the API is stored in the `values` array and displayed in the table. Each row has a checkbox to select a row, and change in checkbox add/ remove item in `checked` array. `checked` array stores the indexes of rows/ values.
A delete button at the end of table is bind with `delete()` method. Once clicked, loop through the `checked` array and delete items from `values` array and changes are reflected automatically.

The loop is in reverse as `slice` method index values changes each time an item is removed from the array.

Here is Plnkr: [Angular delete item from table](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/axRHm8HQ70AgB8zd?open=lib%2Fapp.ts)

Comment: nice example. I've the button outside of *ngFor. I'm looking for ability to delete few entries not one by one. I think here will be another logic.

Comment: @websiteproduct edited my answer to delete multiple items at once.

Comment: `$event.target.checked` in html template was not working for me. I used only `$event` construction. In _component.ts_ I used `isChecked.checked`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can hide elements with `*ngIF` and use `<ng-container>` for your loop:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let sku of value.skus">
   <tr *ngIF="!sku.isAddedToCart">
     <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{sku.id}}"></td>
     <td>{{value.group.name}}</td>
     <td>{{sku.name}}</td>
     <td class="price">{{sku.price}}</td>
   </tr>
</ng-container>
```

With `sku.isAddedToCart` a boolean (for example).

Comment: In this way I will hide only checkboxes not whole object.